# Getting JSON from google spreadsheets

Tags: json, xcode, google-apps-script

I want to get the JSON of my google spreadsheet. I published it to to the app at [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gnmdd6l0PCMo-zdulF8wy3XWcmRQbXMzrfI5l06j38U/pubhtml) url. After researching,I tried retrieving the JSON using this code

```
NSString *theURL = @"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1Gnmdd6l0PCMo-zdulF8wy3XWcmRQbXMzrfI5l06j38U/od6/public/full?alt=json";
NSString *theFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@" %@",theFile);
```

However it didn't work. I am getting null. I am not sure if something is wrong with the code or the url. If there is something wrong with the code please correct me. If something is wrong with the url tell me how to get the right url.

**edit**

This is the [new link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1Gnmdd6l0PCMo-zdulF8wy3XWcmRQbXMzrfI5l06j38U/public/full?alt=json) for JSON. However, i am not getting the values in my sheet. I am getting some other random stuff. How do i get the values from my sheet?

Comment: I used you url and got "Invalid query parameter value for grid_id." Are u sure its correct or that you have all the right permissions? Could you post your error mesage

Comment: so how would i fix it. I shared the document such that anyone with link can view

Comment: Why the Apps-script tag?  Looks like you are using pure xcode.  Is the following documentation relevant?  [iOS Developer - Making HTTP and HTTPS Requests](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ahh yes I know how to do this! However, it is from another Google Apps Script. From another app script you can call code that will access another spreadsheet remotely. Using:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openSpreadsheetByID("your id");
```

Then you have the ability to edit and view any data that you want on that spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

The JSON saving option from Google Spreadsheets became straighforward since the Export Sheet Data add-on is available.

Install this plugin into your Google Spreadsheets and download JSON.

[image]